# Visual C# - Calling a function from a class does nothing

Tags: c#, function, class

I have a problem trying to draw a rectangle on a panel. I created a class that has a function that does this but when I call it nothing happens. When I use the code from the function instead of the actual function it works. Any ideas? This is the code

```
    class Snake : Form1
    {
        public static int x = 20;
        public static int y = 20;
        public static int r = 20;

        public void Draw()
        {
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            Graphics G = panel1.CreateGraphics();
            G.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, r, r);
        }
    }

    //...

    private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Snake s = new Snake();
        s.Draw();
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify what this part of the question means: "When I use the code from the function instead of the actual function it works."

Comment: well if I leave the code as it is, when I click on the panel nothing happens but if I write

SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
Graphics G = panel1.CreateGraphics();
G.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, r, r);

instead of 

Snake s = new Snake();
s.Draw();

it works.

Comment: Every time you click the mouse you are creating a new form, which isn't being displayed, so it's immediately going out of scope and being garbage collected.  I'm guessing you're trying to call the Draw method on an existing form, not create a brand new form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snake object is drawing within its own graphics context, which is not the same as the context of the panel you're clicking. To solve the problem, panel would have to provide graphics for the `Draw` function:

```
class Snake
{
    public static int x = 20;
    public static int y = 20;
    public static int r = 20;

    public void Draw(Graphics G)
    {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        G.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, r, r);
    }
}

//...

private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    using (Graphics G = panel1.CreateGraphics())
    {
        Snake s = new Snake();
        s.Draw(G);
    }
}
```

On a related note, make sure to always dispose of the `Graphics` object.

Answer (score 1):

Implement the Panel Paint event:

```
class Snake : Form1
{
    public static int x = 20;
    public static int y = 20;
    public static int r = 20;

    public void Draw()
    {
      panel1.Refresh() ;
    }

     private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
        Graphics G = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        G.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, r, r);
     }
```

}